# Openssl 1.1.1, How to Set X509_CRL struct's X509_CRL_INFO member's sig_alg member which represents signature algorithm

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am trying to update to OpenSSL 1.1.1 from 1.0.2 and in doing so I have to convert some code. A lot of structures were made opaque in 1.1.0 and now need an accessor and setter functions. For the most part I have found something that works or a suitable workaround. However I can't seem to find any accessor function(s) or suitable way to set X509_xxx_INFO structs members.

```
struct X509_crl_st {
    X509_CRL_INFO crl;          /* signed CRL data */
    ...
};
```

I am trying to set X509_CRL struct's crl member's sig_alg member, but I couldn't find any accessor to crl member through X509_CRL interface.

```
struct X509_crl_info_st {
    ASN1_INTEGER *version;      /* version: defaults to v1(0) so may be NULL */
    X509_ALGOR sig_alg;         /* signature algorithm */
    X509_NAME *issuer;          /* CRL issuer name */
    ASN1_TIME *lastUpdate;      /* lastUpdate field */
    ASN1_TIME *nextUpdate;      /* nextUpdate field: optional */
    STACK_OF(X509_REVOKED) *revoked;        /* revoked entries: optional */
    STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) *extensions;   /* extensions: optional */
    ASN1_ENCODING enc;                      /* encoding of signed portion of CRL */
};
```

If there is no accessor function that can do this I'll greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to do it.

if I make a cast as below to access sig_alg member of X509_CRL_INFO, will this casting bite me in the ass.

```
X509_CRL* crl = X509_CRL_new();
X509_CRL_INFO* crlInfo = (X509_CRL_INFO*)crl;
X509_ALGOR* algPtr = (X509_ALGOR*)(((char*)crlInfo) + sizeof(ASN1_INTEGER*));
X509_ALGOR_set0(algPtr,...);
```

Comment: You're right; there are `{X509,X509_CRL,X509_REQ}_{get0_signature,get_signature_nid}` but setters only for `{X509,X509_REQ}` not `X509_CRL`. Although I don't see a use-case for setting any of them to a value other than the correct value for the signature, and all signers `{X509,X509_CRL,X509_REQ}_sign[_ctx]` set both copies of the sigalg (inside the TBS and outside) to the correct value (and X509,X509_CRL also fix the cached encoding; X509_REQ appears to have a bug).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for your help, but I would like to sign the tbs myself, so at this point I'am thinking a workaround as, make openssl to sign the tbs and get tbs then sign it myself. But here I am having another issue dont know how to get tbs part.